# Trouble implementing parallax background with IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I'm trying to use IntersectionObserver to implement a parallax background scroll effect. I'm not quite sure what combination of threshhold and intersection ratio will allow a continuous effect while the element is either fully or partially in view (it should stop when the element is fully out of view).  I can only get the effect to happen while the element is "intersecting" either the top or the bottom of the viewport.  Here are two attempts I made:

1. I got close to what I want, but when the element is fully in the viewport, there is no parallax. The parallax effect only happens when the element is partially above or below the screen:

   ```
   function observe(selector, threshold, callback) {
     const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
     const options = { rootMargin: '0px', threshold: threshold };
     const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
     for (const element of elements) {
       observer.observe(element);
     }
   }
   function parallax(entries, observer) {
     var scroll, yScroll, elementTop;
     for (const entry of entries) {
     if (entry.isIntersecting) {
         scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
         elementTop = $(entry.target).offset().top;
         yScroll = .5*(scroll - elementTop) + "px";
         $(entry.target).css({"background-position": "50% calc(50% + " + yScroll + ")"});
       }
     }
   }
   function createThreshold() {
     const threshold = [];
     for (let i = 0; i <= 1.0; i += 0.01) {
       threshold.push(i);
     }
     return threshold;
   }
   const threshold = createThreshold();
   observe('.parallax-bg', threshold, parallax);
   ```

Link to fiddle of this attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/pgb9hske/

I also realize that using things like $(window).scrollTop() might possibly be defeating the purpose of using intersection observer, but I couldn't figure out a way to use the intersectionRatio in a math equation to implement the parallax.  I'll worry about that later, I just want to get the effect working when the element is completely in the viewport for now.

2. Here was another attempt, but it's not even close.  The background position just "jumps" when the element crosses the top or bottom of the viewport.

   ```
   const parallax_bgs = document.querySelectorAll('.parallax-bg');
   const parallaxConfig = { root: null, rootMargin: '0px 0px', threshold: 0 };
   parallaxObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries) {
     entries.forEach(function (entry) {
       if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
         scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
         elementTop = $(entry.target).offset().top;
         yScroll = .5*(scroll - elementTop) + "px";
         $(entry.target).css({"background-position": "50% calc(50% + " + yScroll + ")"});
       }
     });
   }, parallaxConfig);
   parallax_bgs.forEach(function (element) {
     parallaxObserver.observe(element);
   });
   ```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I worked around this problem by nesting an element inside the parallax background container.

e.g.

```
<div class="parallax-banner">
<div class="parallax-intersector"></div>
</div>
```

and then applying this scss

```
.parallax-banner {
    height: 800px;
    position: relative;

    .parallax-intersector {
        width: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 50%;
        height: 100vh;
        min-height: 800px;  // the min-height must match the height of your container
        background: #f00;
        z-index: 10;
        transform: translateY(50%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

This gives an element that will always be at least the size of the viewport.

You can then target this element in your intersection observer.

The intersection target element will, when the viewport is larger than your element, start and end above and below your banner, with the offset being equal above and below.

You just need to factor that into your background position calculation.

e.g.

```
let factor = 20;
let offset = (window.innerHeight - entry.target.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height) / 2;
let elapsedPx = (entry.target.getBoundingClientRect().y - window.innerHeight) + offset;
let yScroll = entry.target.parentElement.offsetTop + parseInt(elapsedPx / factor);
```

See example -> https://codepen.io/nxtds/pen/Rwrwbrx

Comment: That's a pretty good workaround. I ended up getting it working by doing something similar to this with GSAP: https://medium.com/elegant-seagulls/parallax-and-scroll-triggered-animations-with-the-intersection-observer-api-and-gsap3-53b58c80b2fa